# What is a good way to transfer complex objects with drag and drop in a UWP app?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have two lists on my c# app, where list1 is listing all objects and list2 is a selection of these objects. I want to enable drag and drop to select objects. But I cannot put these objects in the DataView. How can I solve this?

Comment: All things start with either showing Code, Doing a Google Search or Explaining what the error and or issue is.. how are we supposed to know what you are or are not doing when you don't show us SRC

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please review how to ask a good question because this question is very low quality and doesn't meet the minimum posting standards. Thanks!  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the structure of your object-types, but if it has some identifier, you can use that to store in the `DataView`. Let's say you have a list of `MyClass` objects with a property `ID`, you can put the `ID`'s as text in the `DataView`.

On start of the drag operation you can do this:

```
private void List1_DragItemsStarting(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.DragItemsStartingEventArgs e)
{
    var items = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (MyClass item in e.Items)
    {
        if (items.Length > 0) items.AppendLine();
        items.Append(item.ID);
    }
    e.Data.SetText(items.ToString());
    //As we want our Reference list to say intact, we only allow Copy
    e.Data.RequestedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy;
}
```

In the handler for dropping the selected items you can do this:

```
private async void List2_Dropped(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Text))
    {
        var def = e.GetDeferral();
        var s = await e.DataView.GetTextAsync();
        var ids = s.Split('\n');
        if (ids.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (string id in ids)
            {
                // get the object for the ID here
            }
        }
        e.AcceptedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy;
        def.Complete();
    }
}
```

So instead of passing objects along, you pass ID's along. Hope this is a solution for your situation.